# Запрет переноса строк

Tags: python, python-3.x

в файле 1.txt данные:

```
11f11
ab6f5
kj75g
.....
po87f
```

при склеивании с данных из файла в строку текста после данных переносит строку на записанном файле 2.txt кроме последней строки. Как запретить перенос строки?
мой пример на python:

```
f=open('1.txt', 'r')
s = open('2.txt', 'w')
s1 = "https://www.example.ru/"
s2 = "/home"
for j in f:
    print(s1+j+s2, file=s)
```

Результаты в файле 2.txt:`

```
https://www.example.ru/11f11
/home
https://www.example.ru/ab6f5
/home
https://www.example.ru/kj75g
/home
.....
https://www.example.ru/po87f/home
```

нужны результаты на примере:

```
https://www.example.ru/11f11/home
https://www.example.ru/ab6f5/home
https://www.example.ru/kj75g/home
.....
https://www.example.ru/po87f/home
```

заранее благодарю за ответы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Считанная из файла строка заканчивается на перенос строки (кроме последней строки, под Windows там может не быть переноса строки). Чтобы убрать его, можно воспользоваться методом [`.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) (без параметров просто убирает все пробельные символы с конца строки). В вашем коде просто меняете последнюю строку следующим образом:

```
print(s1 + j.rstrip() + s2, file=s)
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо )))